# Issue toggling caps lock with check box in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I've developed an application (with vb .net) that can toggle caps lock state by clicking on a check box. I've coded the program in such a way that when I click on the checkbox, if it gets checked the caps lock must be turned on and when unchecked it must turn off. Below are the codes.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Private Const VK_CAPITAL As Integer = &H14
Private Const VK_SCROLL As Integer = &H91
Private Const VK_NUMLOCK As Integer = &H90

Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY As Integer = &H1
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

Private Sub checkbutton_caps_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbutton_caps.CheckStateChanged

    If checkbutton_caps.Checked = True Then
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_on.png")

    ElseIf checkbutton_caps.Checked = False Then
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_off.png")

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Now the problem is it's not working as expected. If I check the checkbox, only the image of the checkbox changes but not the caps lock status. The caps lock status changes only when I click on the check box twice. So I need to click on the check box twice to toggle the caps lock. I suspect there's a problem in the way I've used the conditional statements.

Comment: ...Why? Is your caps lock key broken?

Comment: @CodyGray No its not broken, I just want to create a virtual keyboard.

Comment: Start -> Run -> osk.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the conditional logic *per se* (in other words, you've written the `If` statement correctly), but rather the way you are using the `keybd_event` function.

Think about the physical keys on a keyboard. When you "press" a key, two things actually happen: the key goes down, and then the key comes back up. After *both* of those things happen, a key press event is registered as having taken place.

So the proper way to trigger a key press using the `keybd_event` function is to inject a key-down event, followed by a key-up event. So you actually need a pair of calls:

```
 Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
 Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Now that you understand that, look back at your code. The checkbox control starts out unchecked. The first time you click on it, it gets automatically checked and your `CheckedChanged` event handler fires. In response, you make the *first* call to `keybd_event`, which essentially "presses down" the caps-lock key. It is not until the *second* time you click the checkbox control, switching it *back* to unchecked and making the *second* call to `keybd_event` that you actually trigger a full *press* of the caps lock key.

Write the code like so:

```
Private Sub checkbutton_caps_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbutton_caps.CheckStateChanged

    If checkbutton_caps.Checked = True Then
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_on.png")

    ElseIf checkbutton_caps.Checked = False Then
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
        Call keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_off.png")

    End If

End Sub
```

Or, better yet, encapsulate the logic to trigger a key press in another function, reducing code duplication:

```
Private Sub SimulateKeyPress(ByVal bVKCode As Byte, ByVal bScanCode As Byte)
     keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
     keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub checkbutton_caps_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbutton_caps.CheckStateChanged

    If checkbutton_caps.Checked = True Then
        SimulateKeyPress(VK_CAPITAL, &H45)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_on.png")

    ElseIf checkbutton_caps.Checked = False Then
        SimulateKeyPress(VK_CAPITAL, &H45)
        checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_off.png")

    End If

End Sub
```

Even *better* yet, use the [`SendInput` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead of the deprecated `keybd_event` function. This allows you to, among other things, check for and handle errors.

Note that you really don't need the `Call` syntax in VB.NET. That's an old VB 6 thing, and not an idiomatic way to write code in VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problem solved. I never knew how key press events worked, else I wouldn't have committed that mistake.

Comment: `reducing code duplication` if that's the case why not this: `Private Sub checkbutton_caps_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbutton_caps.CheckStateChanged
      keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
      keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
      checkbutton_caps.Image = Image.FromFile(CStr(IF(checkbutton_caps.Checked, "resources\btn_ico_caps_on.png","resources\btn_ico_caps_off.png")))
End Sub`

Comment: @Cody Gray Also something else to point out, the **method**, not ***function*** `SimulateKeyPress` doesn't use the arguments at all, why even classify them and not use them? There's no need for even that method call speaking of reducing code... Good solution as well.